# send http request file through bot framework composer

Tags: botframework, http-post, bots, asp.net-core-webapi, bot-framework-composer

I have web api in asp.net 5 and tried invoke using postman and it successed.

[image]

the simple way just wanna consume from **bot framework composer**. it has been difficult to understand how to send file image through http request post method. `${user.attachments}` is variable that user input in bot.

[image]

[image]

when this scenario got error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

searching for several way it can be implemented using `contentUrl` but in fact it hidden can not be accessed. Is it possible implement that scenario? any suggest will appreciate.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the [link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/3323),and see what `luhan2017` said.

Comment: @YiyiYou already tried but does not solve the problem, finally i change to use bot framework by c# code as alternative

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you need change de value to object.

```
{  "payload": {
"username": "${dialog.selectk.content[0].ticketid}",
"name": "${user.personalname}",
"favoritecolor": "${user.favcolor}",
"profileupdated": "${dialog.userprofileuptodate}"  }}
```